# textarea form not POSTed in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, post, internet-explorer-9

here's the situation:

I have javascript which creates a table layout for a textarea. This is part of a list which users can dynamically add and delete textareas. The use is for a website that allows users to create sets of instructions. The user inputs something and submits. This takes the user to a php file to process the input and redirects the user appropriately.

This javascript works in all browsers except the IE family. The only way it's broken in IE is none of the textareas that are generated send their POST data.

This used to be written in pure javascript, but I recently learned that utilizing a library like jQuery is preferable since that puts some of the burden of maintenance on the jQuery team as new browsers are developed.

Here is the javascript and the html it outputs:

Javascript:

```
var current_step = 1;   

//
// STEP ID NAME CONSTANTS
//
var step_container_id = "stepcontainer_";
var step_title_container_id = "titlecontainer_";
var step_title_id = "steptitle_";
var step_text_container_id="textcontainer_";
var step_text_data = "text_data"; 
var remove_step_id = "remove_step_"; 
var add_step_id = "add_step_";

//
// We'll use a doubly linked list to navigate the instruction structure. 
//
var LIST_HEAD = null; 
var LIST_TAIL = null; 

//
//... Some other javascript functions ...
//

var step = function(instructions, parent_container)
{
    // optional argument, predefined instructions
    this.instructions = instructions;
    this.parent_container = parent_container; 
    //
    // initialzations
    //

    this.identifier = current_step; 
    this.next = null; 
    this.prev = null; 
    this.title = $('<strong></strong>').html( "Step "+current_step+":");

    //
    // Create container
    //
    this.container = $('<li></li>',{id : step_container_id+current_step}); 


    // Create Step 'title' ("Step 1:, Step 2:, etc)
    //
    var step_title_container = $('<div></div>',{id:step_title_container_id+current_step}); 
    step_title_container.append(this.title); 

    //
    // Create the textarea to write the step
    //
    var step_text_container = $('<div></div>',{id:step_text_container_id+current_step}); 
    //
    // Create the layout of the table
    //
    var instruction_layout = $('<table></table>', {width : "100%"}).css("borderSpacing", "10px"); 

    // This row holds the entire instruction form
    var instruction_row = $('<tr></tr>'); 


   // This cell is where users enter step text
   var  text_area_column = $('<td></td>', { width: "70%"}); 


   // This is the second column of our instruction row, and holds the add and delete    button
   var button_column = $('<td></td>', {width: "30%", valign : "middle"}); 
   var add_button_div = $('<div></div>').css("padding" , "5px"); 
   var delete_button_div =  $('<div></div>').css("padding", "5px"); 

   var step_text = $('<textarea></textarea>', {
    id : step_text_data + current_step,
    name : "text[text"+current_step+"]",
    value : this.instructions
    }).css({
        "width" : "80%" , 
        "float" : "left",
        "height" : "80px"
    }); 

    var delete_button = $('<input type="button"></input>')
        .attr({ id :remove_step_id + current_step , value : "-" })
        .css("width" , "20px")
        .addClass('search-autosize')
        .click(function(j) { 
            return function(){ 
                 delete_step.call(this, j); 
    }; 
         }(this))
         .appendTo(delete_button_div); 

    var add_button = $('<input type="button"></input>')
        .attr({id: add_step_id + current_step, value : "+"})
        .css("width", "20px")
        .addClass("search-autosize")
        .click(function(j){
            return function(){
                insert_step.call(this,j);
            };
        }(this))
        .appendTo(add_button_div);

    button_column.append(add_button_div);
    button_column.append(delete_button_div); 

    //
    // Append the containers to the step container
    //
    step_text_container.append(step_text);
    text_area_column.append(step_title_container); 
    text_area_column.append(step_text_container); 
    instruction_row.append(text_area_column); 
    text_area_column.append(button_column); 
    instruction_layout.append(instruction_row);
    this.container.append(instruction_layout);
}
```

** EDIT: ** as per request, the definition of validateForm()

```
function validateForm()
{
var tags = $('#tags');

// Trim whitespace and split on whitespace
tags = tags.val().replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '').split(',');

if(tags.length < 3)
{
//  $('#warning').html('New items require at least three tags');
  //return false;
}

if( ($('#upc').val().length  != 0) &&   ($('#upc').val().length  != 8)  && ($('#upc').val().length  != 12 ))
{
    $('#warning').html('UPC must either be empty, 8 characters, or 12 characters');
     document.getElementById('warning').scrollIntoView(true);
    return false; 
}


if(eliminateDuplicates(tags).length != tags.length)
{
    $('#warning').html('Items cannot have duplicate tags, please remove the duplicates');
     document.getElementById('warning').scrollIntoView(true);
    return false; 
}

var form = document.forms["save"];
if("add" in form)
{
    var upc = form["add"].value;

    if (upc.length != 8 && upc.length != 12)
    {
        $('#warning').html('Please give us a UPC of length 8 or 12');
         document.getElementById('warning').scrollIntoView(true);
        return false;
    }
}
```

output HTML, which is inside the parent_container (an UL, with some id):

```
<form id="save"  enctype="multipart/form-data" name="save_form" method="post" action="item.edit.post.php?itemid=<?=$item->get('itemid');?>" onsubmit='return validateForm()'>
<!-- ... Some other HTML ... -->
<li id="stepcontainer_1">
  <table style="width: 100%; border-spacing: 10px;">
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td style="width: 70%;">
      <div id="titlecontainer_1">
       <strong>Step 1:</strong>
      </div>
      <div id="textcontainer_1">
       <textarea name="text[text1]" id="text_data1" style="width: 80%; height: 80px; float: left;" value=""></textarea>
      </div>
      <td vAlign="middle" style="width: 30%;">
       <div style="padding-top: 5px; padding-right: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-left: 5px;">
        <input class="search-autosize" id="add_step_1" style="width: 20px;" type="button" value="+" />
       </div>
       <div style="padding-top: 5px; padding-right: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-left: 5px;">
        <input class="search-autosize" id="remove_step_1" style="width: 20px;" type="button" value="-" />
       </div>
      </td>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </li>
 <!-- the rest of the list-->
<!-- rest of the website -->
</form>
<-- our footer -->
```

And here is the POST output I get from my PHP file:

in IE 9:

```
array(3) {
 ["item"]=>
   array(8) {
    ["entitytype"]=>
      string(11) "INSTRUCTION"
    ["upc"]=>
      string(8) "12345678"
    ["share"]=>
      string(2) "on"
    ["itemid"]=>
      string(36) "EACB9754-AA81-7B41-B6C9-DDD9D699152B"
    ["thumburl"]=>
      string(0) ""
    ["title"]=>
      string(4) "fdsa"
    ["description"]=>
      string(0) ""
    ["tags"]=>
     string(0) ""
}
["usetemp"]=>
 string(1) "f"
["category"]=>
 array(1) {
  ["Breakfast"]=>
    string(2) "on"
  }
}

utDump
```

Everywhere else:

```
array(5) {
 ["item"]=>
  array(8) {
   ["entitytype"]=>
    string(11) "INSTRUCTION"
  ["upc"]=>
    string(8) "12345678"
  ["share"]=>
    string(2) "on"
  ["itemid"]=>
    string(36) "EACB9754-AA81-7B41-B6C9-DDD9D699152B"
  ["thumburl"]=>
    string(0) ""
  ["title"]=>
   string(4) "fdsa"
  ["description"]=>
    string(0) ""
  ["tags"]=>
    string(0) ""
}
["usetemp"]=>
  string(1) "f"
["category"]=>
  array(1) {
   ["Breakfast"]=>
  string(2) "on"
}
["video"]=>
array(1) {
  ["upc"]=>
    string(8) "12345678"
}
["text"]=>
 array(6) {
  ["upc"]=>
    string(8) "12345678"
  ["text1"]=>
    string(4) "blah"
  ["text2"]=>
    string(4) "blah"
  ["text3"]=>
    string(4) "blah"
  ["text4"]=>
    string(0) ""
  ["text5"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}
```

Notice how IE9 Completely misses the text array from POST

Comment: I've edited the html to show where the form tag would be located. This site has several other input fields, but they all work fine because I don't use javascript to create them

Comment: Where's the definition of `submitForm`? That function is always run on submit, so it's certainly relevant. Can you provide a demo page?

Comment: I have added the definition of the validateForm() function. This function runs fine in IE9

Answer (score 0):

In the mark `textarea` value looks empty. Instead of setting the `value` attribute use `val()` or `html()` method to set the value of textarea. Try this.

```
var step_text = $('<textarea></textarea>', {
    id : step_text_data + current_step,
    name : "text[text"+current_step+"]"
})
.val(this.instructions)//Or use .html(this.instructions)
.css({
    "width" : "80%" , 
    "float" : "left",
    "height" : "80px"
});
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean, if instructions are provided, then the value is set to those. The instructions are provided by data from a database, and generated as an array from PHP. I haven't had issues displaying instructions, it's after the user has edited instructions and clicks the submit button on the page that we have problems. When the page sends POST data, things disappear.